# build_json_object issue with nested JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, nested

I need to get the following JSON object as an output:

```
"{"table" : "test", "column 1" : {"pos" : 1, "name" : "col1", "type" : "integer"}, 
"column 2" : {"pos" : 2, "name" : "col2", "type" : "date"}}"
```

When I use

```
build_json_object('table','test', 'column 1', build_json_object('pos',1,'name','col1','type','integer'), 'column 2', build_json_object('pos',2,'name','col2','type','date'));
```

it throws an error:
ERROR: function build_json_object(unknown,integer, unknown,unknown,  unknown,unknown) does not exist

when I use

```
build_json_object('table','test', 'column 1',('pos',1,'name','col1','type','integer'), 'column 2', ('pos',2,'name','col2','type','date'));
```

it just produces the wrong result:

```
"{"table" : "test", "column 1" : {"f1":"pos", "f2": 1, "f3":"name", "f4": "col1", "f5":"type", "f6": "integer"}, 
    "column 2" : {"f1":"pos", "f2": 2, "f3":"name", "f4": "col2", "f5":"type", "f6": "date"}}"
```

How to generate nested JSON object with build_json_object function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A hint - build the expression step by step starting from the most nested objects. Use proper indents. Note that the expression is somehow similar to the result.
(I've wrapped the main expression with `jsonb_pretty()` to get a nice output):

```
select 
    jsonb_pretty(
        json_build_object(
            'table', 'test',
            'column 1', json_build_object('pos', 1, 'name', 'col1', 'type', 'integer'),
            'column 2', json_build_object('pos', 2, 'name', 'col2', 'type', 'date')
        )::jsonb
    );


       jsonb_pretty        
---------------------------
 {                        +
     "table": "test",     +
     "column 1": {        +
         "pos": 1,        +
         "name": "col1",  +
         "type": "integer"+
     },                   +
     "column 2": {        +
         "pos": 2,        +
         "name": "col2",  +
         "type": "date"   +
     }                    +
 }
(1 row)
```

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks a lot. Looks like changing build_json_object to json_build_object really matters.

Comment: Only now I've noticed that your first attempt was ok, with the exception of the function name. This is because in principle I don't read texts that don't fit on the page ;) Use indents!!

Answer (score 1):

You can nest json objects in constructs via SQL like this

```
SELECT jsonb_pretty(
    data || json_build_object(
        'field', sub.field, 
        'construct', json_build_object(
            'nested', json_build_object(
                'key', 'value', 
                'moved_data', data -> 'nuke_me' -> moved_data
            ),
            'other_nested_key', json_build_object(
                '0', 2136 
            )                       

        )
    ) :: JSONB 
    #- '{nuke_me,moved_data}' 
    #- '{nuke_all_of_me}'
)
AS data FROM table AS sub
ORDER BY "created_at" DESC
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html